# Multi_index issues

Tags: smart-contract, multi-index, eosio.cdt

I'm getting a lot of errors related to multi_index after updating to the newest eosio.cdt. Here is part of my code related to hash.

```
struct st_hash {
   capi_checksum256 hash;
   uint64_t expiration;
   uint64_t primary_key() const { return uint64_hash(hash); }

   uint64_t by_expiration() const { return expiration; }
};


class testclass : public contract {
   public:
     testclass(name self) :
     _hash(_self, _self) {};

   private:
    tb_hash _hash;

}

typedef multi_index<
"hash"_n, st_hash,
indexed_by<"by_expiration"_n,
           const_mem_fun<st_hash, uint64_t, &st_hash::by_expiration>>>
tb_hash;
```

I am getting errors such as:

```
error: constexpr variable 'x' must be initialized by a constant expression
 ...x = eosio::name{std::string_view{eosio::detail::to_const_char_arr<Str...>::value, sizeof...(Str)}};


error: non-type template argument is not a constant
  expression
indexed_by<"by_expiration"_n,


 error: excess elements in scalar initializer
      _hash(_self, _self),

 error: member reference base type 'tb_hash'
  (aka 'int') is not a structure or union
    auto itr = _hash.find(key);

error: no matching constructor for initialization of
  'tb_hash' (aka 'multi_index<operator""_n<char, 'h', 'a', 's', 'h'>(),
  st_hash>')
    : _hash(_self, _self),

 error: member reference base type 'tb_hash'
  (aka 'int') is not a structure or union
    _hash.emplace(_self, [&](st_hash& r) {
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong, or something needs to be changed to use new version of eosio CDT?

Comment: 'uint64_hash' what is this.?  primary key should be of type 'uint'

Comment: It is just a function that converts the hash to uint64_t. I’m not getting any errors with that, I just left it out of the sample code in my post.

Comment: Your _hash table is not assign to a variable , another your class constructor is not according to eosio.cdt version. That's why it showing table name normalization error ` h a s h `

Answer (score 1):

There are huge differences between the old eosio-cpp, the first versions of the cdt and the actual one.

You don't have to initialize the table like you do while the constructor is called.

You also  need to use the Abi-Generator-Attributes instead of multi-index-typedefs.

Take a look here: [Abi-Generator-Attributes](https://eosio.github.io/eosio.cdt/1.5.0/guides/abi-generator-attributes.html)

And here: [Basic Usage](https://eosio.github.io/eosio.cdt/1.5.0/guides/basic-usage.html)

Comment: If i don't initialise in the constructor I get:  error: constructor for testclass explicitly
      initialize the member '_hash' which does not have a default constructor.

Comment: Also I thought the abi attributes only were relevant to generating the abi and not related to the build errors? Is this documentation out of date?: https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cpp/docs/using-multi-index-tables

Answer (score 1):

One issue is that your secondary index is called `"by_expiration"` which is not a valid `eosio::name`.

It needs the same restrictions as any other `name` on EOSIO. Max 12 (actually 13) characters a-z0-5.

Another one is that your class constructor is still the old one. It has changed since eosio.cdt 1.3.
You're also not initializing the superclass `eosio::contract` constructor.
Note that the behavior of the multi-index also changed. It now accepts an `eosio::name` as the first argument but as the second argument it still requires an `uint64_t`. So you need to call `.value` on the second argument.
Here's how I think it should look like:

```
CONTRACT testclass : public eosio::contract {
 public:
  testclass(eosio::name receiver, eosio::name code,
             eosio::datastream<const char *> ds)
      : contract(receiver, code, ds), _hash(receiver, receiver.value) {}
```